# AngularJS promises and ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Using this service to perform promises:

using this service to perform promises: [Improving AngularJS Simple Factory - wrapper around PhoneGap Storage API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420511/improving-angularjs-simple-factory-wrapper-around-phonegap-storage-api/19421504?noredirect=1#19421504)

I can't figure out, why i am getting error when using ng-model directive and promises.

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'favourite'
```

when clicking

```
<div ng-controller="DishCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" name="favourite" ng-model="dish.favourite" required smart-float ng-click="markFavourite(dish)"/>
</div>
```

and controller as follows:

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('DishCtrl', function($scope, NotificationService, MediaService, SQLService, $routeParams, $rootScope) {


    var dishId = $routeParams.dishId;
    SQLService.getDish(dishId).then(function(results) {
      $scope.dish= results;
    });
```

if i remove ng-model directive everything works. So promise is resolved correctly i quess.
I also tried to bind model directly - without promise and works.
Is it a bug, or did i missed something?

I am trying also resolving promises as example in here: http://jsfiddle.net/8HjgJ/

Comment: Show your angular js code here !

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to initialize your scope variable before the promise is resolved. Something like that :

```
angular.module('App')
  .controller('DishCtrl', function($scope, NotificationService, MediaService, SQLService, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
    $scope.dish = false; //Default value, will be updated when promisse is resolved

    var dishId = $routeParams.dishId;
    SQLService.getDish(dishId).then(function(results) {
      $scope.dish= results;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why, but copying the object in Service:

[Improving AngularJS Simple Factory - wrapper around PhoneGap Storage API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420511/improving-angularjs-simple-factory-wrapper-around-phonegap-storage-api/19421504?noredirect=1#19421504before)

before resolving the promise helps!

```
function querySelectSuccess(tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length;
  var output_results = [];

  for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    console.log('ts',results.rows.item(i));

    var temp_copy = angular.copy(results.rows.item(i));
    output_results.push(temp_copy);
  }

  deferred.resolve(output_results);
}
```