# Angularjs and Phonegap database

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Please anyone can suggest me how to create angular factory wrapper to use phonegap database.I tried like:

```
angular.module('mobireward.factory', [])

.factory('dbFactory', function ($q) {
        var countries=[];
        var dbFactory = {};       
        var baseUrl = "http://182.18.157.106:8076/api/MobiRewardServices";       

        dbFactory.GetCountryList = function(){        

            //db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            promisedQuery('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COUNTRY', defaultResultHandler, errorCB);
            promisedQuery('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS COUNTRY (id unique, countryName, countryCode)', defaultResultHandler, errorCB);
            promisedQuery('INSERT INTO COUNTRY (id, countryName, countryCode) VALUES (1, "India", "IN")', defaultResultHandler, errorCB);
            promisedQuery('INSERT INTO COUNTRY (id, countryName, countryCode) VALUES (2, "Pakistan", "PK")', defaultResultHandler, errorCB);

            return promisedQuery('SELECT * FROM COUNTRY', defaultResultHandler, errorCB);           
        };

        function defaultResultHandler(deferred) {
          return function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            var output_results = [];

            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                debugger  
                //alert(results.rows.item(i));
              output_results.push(results.rows.item(i));
            }

            deferred.resolve(output_results);  
          }  
        }

        function defaultErrorHandler(err) {
          alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
        }

        function promisedQuery(query, successCB, errorCB) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql(query, [], successCB(deferred), errorCB);      
          }, errorCB);
          return deferred.promise;  
        }

        // something like private methods
        function errorCB(err) {
          alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
        }

        var db = window.openDatabase("Mobireward", "1.0", "Mobireward", 200000);


        return dbFactory;
});
```

Comment: just courious , why using a phonegap db?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a factory or how to use PhoneGap's db? it's not clear what is being asked here.

Comment: Yeh.. I wanted to use PhoneGap db so want wrap into the factoy? Or please suggest me if any better option

Comment: @sbaaaang Because I am using Angular in Phonegap so want to use inbuild database. Please could you suggest me any other option?

Comment: @No Name well the alternatives are Database on server side, local/session storage and webSQL for client side, but it depends on your needs, cause client side database is not fully supported on all browsers check on caniuse.com for further infos.

Comment: @No Name the thing is : Do you want to run your app only on phonegap? cause i dubt phonegap database will work outside of phonegap ;)

Comment: @sbaaaang Yes I want to run only on phonegap not outside. i am developing on hybrid application and try to synch db from the service and can run offline.

Comment: @No Name ok my suggestion is , if you absolutely sure that your app will one day always run on phonegap use phonegap DB :)

Comment: @sbaaaang thanks, Please can you suggest me any sample how to wrap the phonegap db functionality into the angularjs factory or service.

Comment: @No Name i'm sorry but i never used phonegap plugins into angular try googling i'm sorry :P

Comment: Hi Parwej, do you had any success til now? I'm stuck with the same problem and can't find an online tutorial that leads me step by step to create a connection, insert and select data and show them in an angularJS view.

Comment: @Tipo Yes and I written blog for this. Please go through it: http://www.ictit.com/en/blog/post/28/angularjs-and-phonegap-database/