# Add sqlite query result to angularjs $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite

I have this sqlite query in a angularjs app.

```
 $scope.testArr = [];

 $scope.testFunk = function(){

        var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);

        db.transaction(function(tx){

            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM EVENTS',
                          [],
                          //Callback function with transaction and 
                          //results objects
                          function(tx, results){
                                //Count the results rows
                                var rowsCount = results.rows.length;  
                                //Loop the rows
                                for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
                                    //Build a results string, notice the 
                                    //column names are called

                                    $scope.testArr.push({                   

                                        id: results.rows.item(i).eventId,
                                        nameSel: results.rows.item(i).eventNameSel,
                                        name: results.rows.item(i).eventName,
                                        eventDesc: results.rows.item(i).eventDesc,
                                        eventUrl: results.rows.item(i).eventUrl,
                                        time: results.rows.item(i).eventTime
                                    })

                                }
                                console.log($scope.testArr);
                           },
                           errorHandler);
         });
      }

//
```

The `console.log` returns the right objects, but If I do a `console.log` outside of the `db.transaction` function it returns empty. The problem is that I want to call the `$scope.testFunk()` function and return the result from the query to a variable which I then can process further, like:

```
 var result = $scope.testFunk();
 console.log(result); 
 // prints results from query.
```

Comment: can you set up a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to [use a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420511/improving-angularjs-simple-factory-wrapper-around-phonegap-storage-api).

The reason it's not working now is because when you trying to print the results, it's still not populated. you can add $watch over results and work with it when it's populated.

```
$scope.testFunk(); // modify $scope.results within the function

$scope.$watch('results', function(resultsNewVal, resultsOldVal) {
    console.log(resultsNewVal);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will need some time to go through the code in the linked answer, but in your snippet, what would resultsNewVal and resultOldVal represent in my example?

Comment: for the first time you run testFunk, oldVal would be empty and newVal is the new value pushed whitin the testFunk function